# Turbo Stream not prepending the tweet to my list on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added turbo stream to my rails application. However, my POST works correctly but I have to refresh manually the page to see the new tweet added.

Please could you inform me and lead me in the right direction regarding this matter as it should automatically prepend the tweet to the list.

Please see the code below and review.

```
reset_form_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  reset() {
    this.element.reset()
  }
}
```

```
tweets_controller.html.erb

class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  
  def index
    @tweet = Tweet.new
    @tweets = Tweet.all.order(created_at: :asc)
  end

  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = current_user
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tweet.save
        format.turbo_stream
      else  
        format.html do 
          flash[:tweet_errors] = @tweet.errors.full_messages 
            redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def tweet_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

```
_form.html.erb

<%= form_with model: @tweet, data: { controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" } do |form|  %>
  <% if flash[:tweet_errors] %>
    <div class="bg-red-50 text-red-500 px-3 py-2 font-medium rounded-lg mt-3 mx-3">
      <ul>
        <% flash[:tweet_errors].each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= form.text_area :body, class: "border-b border-t-0 border-x-0 mb-6 px-6 pt-6 block w-full border-gray-200 focus:shadow-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-transparent focus:border-gray-300 resize-none min-h-[180px] text-lg", placeholder: "What's on your mind?" %>

  <div class="flex justify-end px-6 -mt-20">
    <%= form.submit "Tweet", class: "px-6 py-2 bg-sky-400 text-white font-semibold rounded-full text-center cursor-pointer inline-block hover:bg-sky-500 transition ease-in-out duration-300"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
<%= tweet.body %>
```

```
create_turbo_stream.html.erb

<%= turbo_stream.prepend "tweets" do %>
    <%= render "tweet", tweet: @tweet %>
<% end %>
```

```
index.html.erb

<div class="mb-8">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "tweets" do %>
  <%= render @tweets %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `create_turbo_stream.html.erb` => `create.turbo_stream.erb`.

Comment: problem is solved? if so please append [SOLVED] to the title